# Adding objects by value to array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a singleton class for a deck of cards that should create the 52 cards in the constructor.  It looks like this:

```
protected function __construct() {

    global $instance;

    $suits = array("clubs", "spades", "hearts", "diamonds");

    settype($instance->deck, "array");

    foreach ($suits as $suit) {
        for ($i = 1; $i <= 13; $i++) {
            $card = new Card($suit, $i);
            $instance->deck[] = clone $card;
        }
     }
}
```

What I am getting though is all of the objects filled with the King of Diamonds.  Shouldn't the clone keyword prevent this?  Sorry if this is more basic than I can find, I am pretty new to php.

Edit:  Here's the full definitions for the Card, Deck, and the file I'm testing with.  Not the best or most optimal code, but for a quick school assignment.  I had also tried assigning $instance->deck[] directly to a new Card object, but then tried the clone keyword after

Card.php

```
<?php
class Card {

var $suit;
var $cardVal;
var $imageName;

function __construct($suitName, $val) {
    global $suit, $cardVal;

    $suitName = strtolower($suitName);
    if (gettype($val) === "string") {
        $val = strtolower($val);
    }

    switch ($suitName) {
        case 'hearts':
            $suit = 'Hearts';
            break;
        case 'clubs':
            $suit = 'Clubs';
            break;
        case 'diamonds':
            $suit = 'Diamonds';
            break;
        case 'spades':
            $suit = 'Spades';
            break;
        case 'heart':
            $suit = 'Hearts';
            break;
        case 'club':
            $suit = 'Clubs';
            break;
        case 'diamond':
            $suit = 'Diamonds';
            break;
        case 'spade':
            $suit = 'Spades';
            break;
        default:
            $suit = 'Hearts';
    }

    switch ($val) {
        case 1:
            $cardVal = "Ace";
            break;
        case 2:
            $cardVal = "2";
            break;
        case 3:
            $cardVal = "3";
            break;
        case 4:
            $cardVal = "4";
            break;
        case 5:
            $cardVal = "5";
            break;
        case 6:
            $cardVal = "6";
            break;
        case 7:
            $cardVal = "7";
            break;
        case 8:
            $cardVal = "8";
            break;
        case 9:
            $cardVal = "9";
            break;
        case 10:
            $cardVal = "10";
            break;
        case 11:
            $cardVal = "Jack";
            break;
        case 12:
            $cardVal = "Queen";
            break;
        case 13:
            $cardVal = "King";
            break;
        case '1':
            $cardVal = "Ace";
            break;
        case '2':
            $cardVal = "2";
            break;
        case '3':
            $cardVal = "3";
            break;
        case '4':
            $cardVal = "2";
            break;
        case '5':
            $cardVal = "3";
            break;
        case '6':
            $cardVal = "2";
            break;
        case '7':
            $cardVal = "3";
            break;
        case '8':
            $cardVal = "2";
            break;
        case '9':
            $cardVal = "3";
            break;
        case '10':
            $cardVal = "2";
            break;
        case 'jack':
            $cardVal = "Jack";
            break;
        case 'queen':
            $cardVal = "Queen";
            break;
        case 'king':
            $cardVal = "King";
            break;
        case 'j':
            $cardVal = "Jack";
            break;
        case 'q':
            $cardVal = "Queen";
            break;
        case 'k':
            $cardVal = "King";
            break;
        default:
            $cardVal = "Ace";
    }

    $this->setImageName();
}

function SetImageName() {
    global $imageName, $cardVal, $suit;
    $imageName = $cardVal . "Of" . $suit . ".gif";
}

public function GetImageName() {
    global $imageName;

    return $imageName;
}

public function GetSuit() {
    global $suit;

    return $suit;
}

public function GetCardVal() {
    global $cardVal;

    return $cardVal;
}
}
?>
```

Deck.php

```
<?php
class Deck {

private static $instance;
public $deck = array();

// The singleton method
public static function singleton()
{
    if (!isset(self::$instance)) {
        $class = __CLASS__;
        self::$instance = new $class;
    }
    return self::$instance;
}

protected function __construct() {

    global $instance;

    $suits = array("clubs", "spades", "hearts", "diamonds");

    settype($instance->deck, "array");

    foreach ($suits as $suit) {
        for ($i = 1; $i <= 13; $i++) {
            $card = new Card($suit, $i);
            $instance->deck[] = clone $card;
        }
    }
}

function PrintDeck() {
    global $instance;

    foreach ($instance->deck as $card) {
        echo $card->GetImageName() . '<br>';
    }
}
}
?>
```

Calling from:

```
<?php

include './models/Deck.php';
include './models/Card.php';

$deck = Deck::singleton();

$deck->printDeck();
?>
```

Thanks.  Probably something stupid or me being stupid.

Comment: Why are you using `clone` and not just adding the new card directly to the array?

Comment: paste a definition of class Deck (do you have a `static` property `$instance` declared?) and your Card constructor (just in case)

Comment: Show your code in the `Card` and `Deck` class. Also @newfurniturey is right. It doesn't makes sense to clone the object here. It's cheaper and faster to just add the card directly to your array (`$instance->deck[] = new Card($suit, $i);`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues here that are preventing this from working the way you expect (technically fixing only the first will get the cards to display, but let's fix them both for a better fundamental application).

The first issue is with the way the `Card` class is treating [variable scope](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php), specifically via the use of the `global` keyword. `global` pulls variable definitions from, well, the global scope; in this case, it's looking for definitions of `$suit`, `$cardVal` and `$imageName` outside of the `Card` class, not the class's member variables. What you'll want to use instead is the `$this` operator:

**Card.php** (note: I cleaned up the `switch` statements a little too to save space / readability)

```
<?php
class Card {
    var $suit = '';
    var $cardVal = '';
    var $imageName = '';

    function __construct($suitName, $val) {
        $suitName = strtolower($suitName);
        $val = is_string($val) ? strtolower($val) : $val;

        switch ($suitName) {
            case 'clubs':
            case 'club':
                $this->suit = 'Clubs';
                break;
            case 'diamonds':
            case 'diamond':
                $this->suit = 'Diamonds';
                break;
            case 'spades':
            case 'spade':
                $this->suit = 'Spades';
                break;
            case 'hearts':
            case 'heart':
            default:
                $this->suit = 'Hearts';
        }

        if (($val >= 2) && ($val <= 10)) {
            $this->cardVal = $val;
        } else {
            switch ($val) {
                case 11:
                case 'jack':
                case 'j':
                    $this->cardVal = "Jack";
                    break;
                case 12:
                case 'queen':
                case 'q':
                    $this->cardVal = "Queen";
                    break;
                case 13:
                case 'king':
                case 'k':
                    $this->cardVal = "King";
                    break;
                case 1:
                case 'ace':
                default:
                    $this->cardVal = "Ace";
            }
        }

        $this->setImageName();
    }

    private function SetImageName() {
        $this->imageName = $this->cardVal . "Of" . $this->suit . ".gif";
    }

    public function GetImageName() {
        return $this->imageName;
    }

    public function GetSuit() {
        return $this->suit;
    }

    public function GetCardVal() {
        return $this->cardVal;
    }
}
```

By making the above change, the cards should all display. However, there is one remaining fundamental issue and that is with the singleton design of the `Deck` class. Throughout it, it refers to `self::$instance->deck` where it *should* be accessing it as `$this->deck` instead. The static / singleton idea is for `$instance` only; outside usage of the object will call member functions which then access single-member properties (in this case, the global `$deck`):

**Deck.php** (note: I also removed the `clone` call - it was unnecessary)

```
<?php
class Deck {
    private static $instance;
    public $deck = array();

    public static function singleton() {
        if (!static::$instance) {
            $class = __CLASS__;
            static::$instance = new $class;
        }
        return static::$instance;
    }

    protected function __construct() {
        $suits = array("clubs", "spades", "hearts", "diamonds");

        foreach ($suits as $suit) {
            for ($i = 1; $i <= 13; $i++) {
                $this->deck[] = new Card($suit, $i);
            }
        }
    }

    public function PrintDeck() {
        foreach ($this->deck as $card) {
            echo $card->GetImageName() . '<br>';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect.  Thanks so much.  Scope is handled so differently from other languages I am familiar with (C#, objective-c, java, etc...) that I guess I need to do a little more research.  Corrected examples were spectacular as well.